# How to change filepath structure using automator (windows to mac)?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, windows

I use a mac at work and people send me windows file paths all day. Does anyone know how to convert the filepath using applescript in an automator so I can right click in an email and then open it?

Windows path: `\\Sfa66\devmrkdt$\Donor Relations\FY14\Events\Invitation\Email`

Mac path: `smb://Sfa66\devmrkdt$/Donor Relations/FY14/Events/Invitation/Email`

This answer was so close [How to translate between Windows and Mac -style file locations?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-mac-style-file-locations) but it won't work when there are blank spaces in the file path.

Answer (score 1):

Blank spaces have to be escaped. To escape a special character, like a blank space, you use a forward slash, so " " will become "\ ".

You can modify the script, [https://gist.github.com/2211017](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2211017), link to from the post you linked to by adding the following line `set mytext to searchReplace(mytext, " ", "\ ")` after line 16.

```
...
15. set mytext to searchReplace(mytext, ">.", "")
16. set mytext to searchReplace(mytext, ">", "")

17. set mytext to searchReplace(mytext, " ", "\ ")

18. set findIt to "\\"
19. set replaceIt to "/"
...
```

Answer (score -4):

I created three Mac automator scripts based on internet code snippets for task of this question. Enjoy.

URL: https://github.com/marcoziti/mactoys

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.