# Automator Apple Script sometimes work, sometimes doesn't

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, path

I've wrote (and collected from different places on the internet) an Automator Apple Script to share network drive locations between Windows and Macs.

It works that all mac users can rightclick a file and copy the Windows path of it. The windows user can just copy paste it into explorer. If the Windows user wants to share a location he just copies the normal Windows path from explorer and all mac users that want to access that location highlight the path and execute another script that transforms it back to a mac path.

I have some trouble with the opening part. For quite some time I was the only Mac user using this script. Now I installed the script to other Macs and ran into issues.

Sometimes the path doesn't open, sometimes it does. On my machine it works everytime.

Here some example:
Windows path:
`\\Ourservername\Somefolder\Some_sub_folder\` would convert into:
`smb://Ourservername/Somefolder/Some_sub_folder/`

On the other Mac I tested it it seems pretty random when it works. So I have no idea why it's not working there 100% of time.

The "working" Mac uses BigSur and the "non working" uses Monterey. But it just recently updated and before on Catalina it wasn't working either 100% of the time.

Here is the script:

```
on searchReplace(theText, SearchString, ReplaceString)
    set OldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to SearchString
    set newText to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ReplaceString
    set newText to newText as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to OldDelims
    return newText
end searchReplace

on run {input, parameters}
    
    set myClip to the input
    set mylocation to searchReplace(myClip, "<", "")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, ">.", "")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, ">", "")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "\\", "/")
    set mylocation to "smb:" & mylocation
    # fix issue with spaces and other characters
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, " ", "%20")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "!", "%21")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "#", "%23")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "$", "%24")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "%", "%25")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "&", "%26")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "'", "%27")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "(", "%28")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, ")", "%29")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "*", "%2A")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "+", "%2B")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, ",", "%2C")
    #set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, ".", "%2E")
    #set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "/", "%2F")
    #set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, ":", "%3A")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, ";", "%3B")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "=", "%3D")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "?", "%3F")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "@", "%40")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "[", "%5B")
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "]  ", "%5D")
    
    considering case
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "Ä", "%C3%84")
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "ä", "%C3%A4")
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "Ö", "%C3%96")
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "ö", "%C3%B6")
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "Ü", "%C3%9C")
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "ü", "%C3%BC")
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "ß", "%C3%9F")
        set mylocation to searchReplace(mylocation, "ẞ", "%E1%BA%9E")
    end considering
    
    
    tell application "Finder"
        open location mylocation
    end tell
    
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
    end tell
    
    
    return input
end run
```

*Quick note to the script: While pasting it I just noticed that I commented some characters out (`.` `/` `:`). If I remember correctly I did that because it messed up the `smb://` part. But I will test around here a little bit. But still, why is it working on one Mac, but not the other?*

This might be worth a second question: But if you know any better way of doing this (sharing network locations between Windows and Mac, maybe an app?) I would be thankful to know about them!

Comment: Presumably you've already seen this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144916/how-to-change-filepath-structure-using-automator-windows-to-mac

Comment: AppleScript can be a bit fussy about the type of filepath data (e.g. `with POSIX path to file`).

Comment: Thanks. But I already escape the spaces and any other special character. The weird part is: It's the exact same script, the exact same server, exact same network, exact same file I want to link. Only the mac is a different one and on one it doesn't work from time to time.

Comment: What are the actual symptoms of 'not working'? Can you get it to spit out the revised URL to text so you can check it?

Comment: @Tetsujin Good idea. My current script brings the finder on top. When it's "not working" the finder goes in front but doesn't connect to the network share.

Comment: omg. I found the issue. Thanks @Tetsujin for that simple idea. Don't know why I didn't came up with this myself.
So, the problem is: The messenger we use has the feature to "like" messages. When I highlight the path (and pay attention to not to highlight the like button), the like button still gets processed some times which end up in a link like this: `smb://Ourservername/Somefolder/Some_sub_folder/%2520Gef%C3%A4llt%2520mir12:17`. This happens only sometimes (with no visual indication) and I'm not sure how to work around this without having the user to copy the link, paste it somewhere and

Comment: highlight it again to open it...

Comment: @jona Well, you could run a function to detect the error on the path variable and remove it when present, so you can select the like button (or not) as well.