# Convert Mac to Windows paths and visa-versa for sharing with colleagues

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, path

Wanted to share perhaps a more thorough answer to this question, where the solution does not satisfy.

Reference:
[How to translate between Windows and Mac -style file locations?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-mac-style-file-locations)

**PROBLEM**

From a Mac, I want to copy a file path on a network share into an email so that its clickable by poor Windows recipients.

Example:
smb://servername/MLS/Timbers/IrrefutableProofTimbersAreBestTeamInMLS.pdf

Expected Output:
\\servername\MLS\Timbers\IrrefutableProofTimbersAreBestTeamInMLS.pdf

This should also work the other way around, when a `Mac User` wants to send a link to to a `Windows User`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. - please put your solution in the answer section.

Comment: just found a 3rd party app: [LinkConverter](https://apps.apple.com/app/linkconverter/id1604758881) easy way to convert and manage your macOS and Windows network share links via the clipboard

Comment: Anyone tried this with automator? [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5630586](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5630586)