# Can't import automator workflow "document can't be opened"

Tags: applescript, automator, big-sur

I found this "question" [Convert Mac to Windows paths and visa-versa for sharing with colleagues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276094/convert-mac-to-windows-paths-and-visa-versa-for-sharing-with-colleagues) 
Which lead me over different detours to this github: https://github.com/marcoziti/mactoys

I downloaded the .workflow files, but unfortunately I can't open them.
When double clicking, nothing is happening. When I start automator and select the file to open it  has a popup: Document "XY" can't be opened (I translated the error from german).

Any idea why this happens? I thought I could just import the script.

I'm currently running BigSur 11.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are not Automator workflows, they are just raw text AppleScripts.

You'll need to create your own Automator workflow, and paste those scripts into the Run AppleScript action.

The last edit, 3 year ago, was to rename the scripts as `.workflow`, which is an error.